# How to get "\n" as an input and cout as new line

Tags: c++

I want to get the string `"hello \n world"` as an input, and cout the `\n` in the string as a new line. When I write `\n` in the terminal, it can compile as a new line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string st;
    getline(cin, st);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Remember that in most contexts, `\n` is just two unspecial characters, and only in certain contexts is `\n` translated to newline, which is actually control character 10.

Comment: I know, \n is two unspecial characters, but i need to get this part of string in order to cout new line. I tried loops and if/else statements and it worked, but it was also printing \n this string and i just want to cout new line.

Comment: cout is a target, not a verb.  You `<<` or print to cout , you don't "cout" something.  Have you looked at `endl` ?

Answer (score 3):

When you pass "\n" as a console input, it is considered as two separate characters - '\' and 'n'.

To achieve what you want, you will need to replace these two characters with new-line character manually.

You can achieve that like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    // find the index where "\n" sequence starts
    const size_t index = line.find("\\n");
    // from there, replace two chars (size of the sequence) 
    // with new string - containing only '\n' character
    std::cout << line.replace(index, 2, "\n");

}
```

When executed, this will be the output (with first line being the input):

```
hello \n world
hello 
 world
```

This behavior can be simply generalized in creating a function, which takes string, sought sequence and replacing sequence as parameters and returns new string with replaced sequence. Something like:

```cpp
std::string replace_sequence_in_with(const std::string& line, 
                                     const std::string& sequence, 
                                     const std::string& replaceWith) {
    const auto index = line.find(sequence);
    if (index == std::string::npos) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Subsequence " + sequence + " not found.");
    }
    return line.replace(index, sequence.size(), replaceWith);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but is it necessary to get pointer as an argument?

Comment: Do you mean the arguments to the *replace_sequence_in_with* function?
Those are actually not pure pointers but actually *references*. Reference is basically the same as a pointer but with slight modification - it can never be null/nullptr. Reference always has to refer to something. Therefore you can be sure that nobody passed a nullptr to your function. Second slight difference is that you can refer to object's member functions with '.' instead of a '->' as with a traditional pointer. 
But the main reason why it is there is that you do not copy the string when you don't need to.

Comment: @markovd in your `replace_sequence_in_with()` function, the `line` parameter should be `const`, since the function returns a new `string`. Also, `const index = ...` is missing a type, use `std::string::size_type` or `auto`. Also, you are not accounting for the possibility that `find()` might not find the `sequence` (passing `std::string::npos` to `replace()` may throw an `out_of_range` exception).

Comment: @markovd why throw an exception if the `sequence` is not found? Just return the original string as-is. In any case, `replace()` is not a  `const` method, it modifies in-place, so it can't be called on a `const std::string`. Since the function returns a new `std::string` anyway, a copy needs to be made one way or the other, so just make the copy and then modify it: `const auto index = line.find(sequence); if (index == std::string::npos) { return line; } auto ret = line; ret.replace(index, sequence.size(), replaceWith); return ret;`